# C++:,when i use string array, it comes string subscript out of range

Tags: c++, string

I just want to know why it come the question that string subscript out of range,I have already initialized the string array.Thank you.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#define N 100000
using namespace std;
string s[N + 5] = {}, ss[N + 5] = { " " }, fs[N + 5] = { " " };
int main()
{
   int n, x; char c;
   cin >> n;
   for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j<6; ++j)
       {
          scanf("%c", &c);//the error comes here.
          if (c == ' ') continue;
          s[i] += c;
       }
      ss[i] = s[i] + s[i];
      for (int j = 5; j >= 0; --j) fs[i][j] = s[i][5 - j];
   }
   int flag = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i<n; ++i)
   {
      for (int j = 0; j<n; ++j)
     {
        if (i == j) continue;
        if (find(s[i], fs[j]) || find(s[i], ss[j]))
        {
            flag = 1; break;
        }
      }
 }
```

}

Comment: what have you enter for `n` ?

Comment: the input is 
2
1 2 3 4 5 6
3 2 1 6 5 4
but the program failed when it reads the second line

Comment: Can you please help to help you? 1: Where are you defining `N`. 2: What is `n` (what number)? 3: plese format your code, it simple miss brace, but only you know where.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: oh, i would submit the complete code

Comment: N and n is not the same. although dont you want to put semicolon at the end of the ++i and ++j ?

Comment: @Vishwa I think `N` is a predefined "maximum size". And as well a semicolon after `++i` and `++j` would be a syntax error.

Comment: On the updated code, try using **int** or **string**. sometimes **char** can cause some weird errors. @iBug yes, that's what i implemented about **N** and **n**

Comment: At the start, I surely used int, it comes the same question

Comment: Mixing `cin` and `scanf` is a horrible idea.

Comment: Do not `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) [Why should I not #include `<bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

2) Avoid global variables and use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) when size is unknown.

3) [Why is `using namespace std` considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

You're getting an out of range error because of `fs[i][j]` accessing empty strings `f[i]`.

Comment: I'm sorry that I can't understand the reason, and the error seems to occur before the sentence

Comment: @田宇航 `string fs[N + 5] = { " " }` declares `N+5` **empty** strings. Indexing them with `fs[i][j]` without filling them first is wrong as they're empty.

Comment: std::string s[N + 5] = {"123456"}, ss[N + 5] = { "123456" }, fs[N + 5] = { "123456" }; 
Can I modify the code like this?

Comment: @田宇航 That would only initialize the first string. The `N+4` others would be empty. Don't forget my 2).

Comment: I add the module.
for (int i = 0; i < N + 5; ++i)
 {
  s[i] = "123456"; ss[i] = 123456; fs[i] = "123456";
 }
and it seems work

Comment: @田宇航 Or simply `std::vector<std::string> fs(n, "123456");` ;)